# Substring в Oracle

Tags: регулярные-выражения, postgresql, oracle

Нужно извлечь подстроку по regexp выражению в Oracle. Например, для `/root/abc/dev` нужно извлечь `abc/dev`, но при этом не нужно ничего извлекать при `/root/item/abc/dev`. То есть `/root/item/(.*)` - особый случай. Для PostgreSQL можно сделать вот так:

```
substring('/root/abc/dev/item', '\/root\/(?!(item))(.*)')
```

Как сделать такое же для Oracle? Такой способ не работает:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('/root/abc/def', '\/root\/(?!(item))(.*)')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Так, здесь берется 3 группа - (.*) (указывается как последний параметр функции), если присутствует 'item/', иначе null</s>

<s>SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('/root/item/abc/dev', '(/root/)(item/)(.*)', 1, 1, 'i', 3) FROM DUAL;</s>

Или через CASE и REGEXP_LIKE

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NOT REGEXP_LIKE('/root/abc/dev', '(\/root\/)(item/)') THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR('/root/abc/dev', '(\/root\/)(.*)', 1, 1, 'i', 2) ELSE NULL END
      FROM DUAL;
```

Oracle немного беден на синтаксис Subexpressions, поэтому так

[Using Regular Expressions in Database Applications, Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_regexp.htm#i1011021)

Comment: @Mike да, вы правы, тогда только проверкой через REGEXP_LIKE, получается

Comment: У меня еще так `REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(TEXT, '\/root\/|item/|.*', 1, 2),'item/','')` получилось. но есть некоторые ограничения. если `item/` где то далее в тексте есть то оно будет вырезано, хотя это можно починить с помощью regexp_replace. Но все равно громоздко :(

Comment: Это да, на самом деле удивительно, что этих базовых вещей нет все еще

Answer (score 1):

Если прям одной регуляркой, то тогда вот так:

`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('/root/item/abc/dev/rteg/wgw', 
                      '(/root/)([^(item)]+.*)', 1, 1, 'i', 2) 
FROM DUAL;`

Даже если `item` будет встречаться дальше в строке, он отбрасываться не будет и все, что после второго (3,4,..,n) `item`'a также отброшено не будет.